# Running a rich presence from a bot command

Tags: discord.js

Want to use commands to be able to switch between rich presences. Have a main server management bot, trying to have it require my app.js file (in another folder) when I run "rHW". Whenever I run it, its all good and is running the rich presence, but I get the error: "connection closed at IPCTransport. (C:\Users\JeffofBread\Desktop\HW Presence\node_modules\discord-rpc\src\client.js:118:16)". Never happens when I just enter "node ." into terminal so I assume my rich presence code is fine, but dont know. Any ideas?

```
if (message.author.username === 'JeffOfBread'){
  rHW = require('C:/Users/JeffofBread/Desktop/HW Presence/app.js')
  message.channel.send('Homework Rich Presence: On')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found a solution. Had to do for some reason with the files running under different folders. Just moved them into the same folder, changed the path to the file, and it ran fine.